Extracting and rearranging substrings
I have a string containing a date in the form DD.MM.YYYY and would like to convert it to the format YYYYMMDD. No error checking is necessary, since I can ensure that the input string has the correct format. How can this be done in an compact way? NOTE: I'm interested in a solution doing it purely based on string processing, and not in creating and formatting Date objects.
I came up with the straightforward solution
s ="14.04.2023"
sx = String.slice(s, 6, 4) <> String.slice(s, 3, 2) <> String.slice(s, 0, 2)

This works, but there is a lot of typing. Is there a more "Elixir-like" approach? For instance, in Ruby I would perhaps do a
sx = s.match(/(..).(..).(....)/).captures.reverse.join

which would be clearer IMO, because the regex shows which parts of the string are extracted, and the reverse.join tells us how these parts are put together again. I wonder how a similar approach would be done in Elixir, or how experienced Elixir programmer would approach this task.

Does this answer your question? Format date with Elixir

@Daniel : The linked question is useful, but I was interested here in approaches using string manipulation, not in converting the strings to date objects. I will update the question to clarify this point.

using the approach to convert string to string excludes validation and is error-prone. I would recommend to first convert the string to a validated structure.

@Daniel : That's why I explicitly mentioned, that validation is not necessarily in my  case. Actually, previous steps in my function ensure, that I receive as input only strings of the correct format. However, since I'm still at the start of learning Elixir, I would like to learn about how to write good string manipulation routines.

@Daniel : One more point: I also researched, out of interest, the approach with date formatting in the page which you linked to, but I didn't find a way to create a date object out of my string. In Ruby, I would use something like Date.parse, where I can specify the format explicitly. In Elixir, it seems that strings can only be parsed, if they comply with the ISO 8601 specification for a date.


As Everett pointed out, binary pattern matching is the best way to approach this. Compared to Regular expressions it's much more explicit, reliable, and efficient.
def format(<<dd::binary-2, ".", mm::binary-2, ".", yyyy::binary-4>>) do
  yyyy <> mm <> dd
end

Using it:
iex(1)> Example.format("14.04.2023")
"20230414"

It also gives you a FunctionClauseError if you pass an invalid value:
iex(2)> Example.format("14.04.23")
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Example.format/1

    The following arguments were given to Example.format/1:

        # 1
        "14.04.23"


You could also simplify your answer with String.split, but I think the binary matching is better. Some people find it hard to understand, so may prefer this, though:
iex(3)> "14.04.2023" |> String.split(".") |> Enum.reverse() |> Enum.join()
"20230414"


I was not aware that you could do the matching for the fields in the parameter list of the function definition already. This is great and looks, for me at least, pretty readable.

Just curious Adam--where did you find that binary-<size> notation?  I mean like binary-2.  I don't believe I've ever seen that one.  All the examples in the doc you link are binary-size(<size>) i. e. binary-size(2).

@OnorioCatenacci check the Shortcut Syntax section. The example there doesn't specify the type so is using an implicit integer- but it also works with binary and all the other types.

Given the premise of your question (i.e. that you are 100% sure of the input format, you do not need to validate the date, and you are interested in native string processing), consider the following deconstruction:
iex> <<mm::binary-size(2), ".", dd::binary-size(2), ".",  yyyy::binary-size(4)>> = "04.12.2024"
"04.12.2024"

This will bind the variables so that mm = "04", dd = "12", and yyyy = "2024".  The ::binary-size(n) is a useful modifier when parsing strings when you know exactly how many characters each segment has.

Interesting alternative, though it does not really look simpler than my approach, plus it needs three additional variables. But I'm glad to see this solution, because it would not have occured to me to use this kind of pattern match. Do you happen to know where I can find a complete list of all modifiers for String objects?

I'm only aware of ::binary and ::binary-size(n) https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/main/binaries-strings-and-charlists.html

@user1934428  binary matching is much more preferable than Regex, and is super fast. To finish the answer: yyyy <> mm <> dd

@Everett the types/modifiers are listed in the docs for the <<>> operator https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/main/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#<<>>/1 My personal preference is to shorten binary-size(n) to n-bytes, such as <<d::2-bytes, ?., m::2-bytes, ?., y::4-bytes>> = "14.04.2023".

@AdamMillerchip : Good information. I think I will consider this approach if performance is of importance, though for readability, I would perhaps go for the variant Brett Beatty suggested in his comment. Also, I appreciate your idea of using split.

I figured out a solution, which is patterened along the Ruby solution posted in the question:
Regex.run(~r/(..).(..).(....)/, s) |> Kernel.tl |> Enum.reverse |> Enum.join

It's still a lot of typing, but I can't see how to make it more compact....
